# Getting a value from a table through a foreign key in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable, foreign-keys, show, relationship

Hi I have created two models,

```
class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team_id, :home_score, :home_team_id, :result, :week
 belongs_to :team, :class_name => Team
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :form, :name
 has_many :fixtures, :class_name => Fixture, :foreign_key => :home_team_id
 has_many :fixtures, :class_name => Fixture, :foreign_key => :away_team_id
end
```

In my fixtures table I store a team_id in the home_team_id and away_team_id columns.

Then in my fixtures/show.html.erb I show the id stored

```
<p>
  <b>Home team:</b>
  <%= @fixture.home_team_id %>
</p>
```

How can I show the team.name from the teams table by getting the team.id stored in the fixtures table?

I need to change this line <%= @fixture.home_team_id %> to something else but not sure what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference

With `belongs_to` you can access it with: `@fixture.team` since your defining a one to many relationship it should never have both `home_team_id` and `away_team_id` and will access the appropriate one.

Comment: I tried @fixture.team.team_id(fixture.home_team_id).name gives me an error how can I call the team with a value from the home_team column in the fixtures table?

Comment: Oh you need to use the `foreign_key` option in the `belongs_to` as well. So you will need 2 `belongs_to` statements like `belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => Team, :foreign_key => :home_team_id` and access them as `@fixture.home_team`